# Dificuldade de definição do charset no PHP

Tags: php, codificação-de-caracteres, xampp, localhost

Tentei fazer um programa que atribua uma determinada sequência de cor a todos os caracteres, mas o resultado não é o esperado e tudo indica que tenha a haver com o a definição do "*charset*".

Seguidamente vou colocar o código e junto uma imagem da saída do teste na expectativa que alguém me diga o que estou a fazer mal.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Mudar a cor das letras</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
      header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
      $cor=array("blue","#00b300","red","black","#ff9900","#ff0066",
                 "#cc00cc","#00ccff","#336600","#996600","#ff00ff","#66ccff");
      $nelcor=count($cor);
      $texto="educação123";
      echo $texto; echo "<br/>";
      $nletras1=strlen($texto);//??? conta mais caracteres ex: ã=2
      $nletras=mb_strlen($texto, 'utf8');
      echo "strlen= ".$nletras1."<br>"."mb_strlen= ".$nletras."<br>"; 

      if ($nletras==0) {
        echo "Não há texto"; goto fim;
      }

      $vtexto = str_split($texto);//transformar string (cadeia ou texto) em array 
      (vector)
      $contador = 0; //ler letra a letra todo o texto
      while($contador <= $nletras-1) {
          $ncor=$contador%$nelcor;
          echo "<font size='5' color=$cor[$ncor]>$vtexto[$contador]</font>"; 
          $contador++;
      } 
      fim:;
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: printscreen com a tela do navegado.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `str_split` não funciona com unicode

Use `preg_split('//u', $texto, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);` e salve o documento como **UTF-8 sem BOM**, assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Mudar a cor das letras</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$cor=array("blue","#00b300","red","black","#ff9900","#ff0066",
"#cc00cc","#00ccff","#336600","#996600","#ff00ff","#66ccff");
$nelcor=count($cor);
$texto="educação123";
echo $texto;echo "<br/>";
$nletras1=strlen($texto);//??? conta mais caracteres ex: ã=2
$nletras=mb_strlen($texto, 'utf8');
echo "strlen= ".$nletras1."<br>"."mb_strlen= ".$nletras."<br>"; 
if ($nletras==0) {
echo "Não há texto"; goto fim;
}
$vtexto = preg_split('//u', $texto, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);//transformar string (cadeia ou texto) em array 

$contador = 0; //ler letra a letra todo o texto
while($contador <= $nletras-1) {
$ncor=$contador%$nelcor;
echo "<font size='5' color=$cor[$ncor]>$vtexto[$contador]</font>"; 
$contador++;
} 
fim:;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Resolvido e muito mais rápido do que pensava.           Obs: Usei o Notepad++ com a codificação utf-8 sem BOM

Comment: Como ou onde faço essa marcação?