# Echo colorido em php

Tags: php, html, echo

Tem como deixar o ECHO em PHP colorido ? Imprimir no HTML, letra por letra colorido ex:

```
if (strpos($d5, '{"name":"')) {
    echo 'LIVE ->' . $a . '|' . $b . ' | C:' . $c . '';

} else {
    echo "DEAD -> $a|$b ";
}
```

Tudo que der LIVE e DEAD (imprimido na tela) sair tudo colorido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usar `str_split`, `explode` ou até mesmo iterar string não vai funcionar se acaso estiver usando **unicode** (UTF-8 por exemplo), como explicado em:

- [str_split não funciona bem em string contendo UTF-8?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111131/3635)
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/260398/3635

Para isto você pode usar `preg_split` com o modificador `u`, assim:

```
preg_split('//u', $texto, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Usei como base esta resposta https://stackoverflow.com/a/25996226/1518921 para gerar as cores, deve ser algo como:

```
<?php

function mb_text_color($texto)
{
    $letters = preg_split('//u', $texto, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    foreach ($letters as &$letter) {
        if (trim($letter) === '') continue;

        $cor = dechex(rand(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF));
        $letter = '<span style="color:#' . $cor . '">' . $letter . '</span>';
    }

    return implode('', $letters);
}

echo mb_text_color('foo bár');
```

Para usar, pode fazer assim:

```
if (strpos($d5, '{"name":"')) {
    echo mb_text_color('LIVE ->' . $a . '|' . $b . ' | C:' . $c);

} else {
    echo mb_text_color("DEAD -> $a|$b ");
}
```

Ou assim:

```
if (strpos($d5, '{"name":"')) {
    echo 'LIVE ->' . mb_text_color($a . '|' . $b . ' | C:' . $c);

} else {
    echo 'DEAD -> ' . mb_text_color("$a|$b ");
```

Ou variável por variável, como você desejar.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer uma função que gera essas letras coloridas.

```
function geraLetrasColorida($palavra) {

    // Separa as letras
    $letras = str_split($palavra);

    // Percorre todas as letras
    foreach($letras as $letra) {

        // Gera uma cor aleatória baseado no hexadecimal da cor.
        $cor = dechex(mt_rand(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF));

        // Imprimi o html com a letra gerada.
        echo "<span style=\"color:#{$cor}\">".$letra."</span>";
    }
}
```

Dessa forma (a cima), você consegue pegar uma palavra e gerar letras coloridas apenas chamando essa função.

```
geraLetrasColorida("Não sei, só sei que foi assim!");
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!